# multi updating a key along the documents of a collection using pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have lots of documents inside a collection. 
The structure of each of the documents inside the collection is as it follows:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId(....),
"valor" : {
    "AB" : {
        "X" : 0.0,
        "Y" : 142.6,
    },
    "FJ" : {
         "X" : 0.2,
         "Y" : 3.33

 ....
```

The collection has currently about 200 documents and I have noticed that one of the keys inside `valor` has the wrong name. In this case we will say "FJ" shall be "JOF" in all the docs of the collection.

Im pretty sure it is possible to change the key in all the docs using the `update` function of pymongo. The problem I am facing is that when I visit the online doc available https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.update/  only explains how to change the values(which I would like to remain how they currently are and change only the keys).

This is what I have tried:

```
def multi_update(spec_key,key_updte):
    rdo=col.update((valor.spec_key),{"$set":(valor.key_updte)},multi=True)
    return rdo

print(multi_update('FJ','JOF'))
```

But outputs `name 'valor' is not defined` . I thought I shall use valor.specific_key to access to the corresponding json

how can I update a key only along the docs of the collection?

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems. First, `valor` is not an identifier in your Python code, it's a field name of a MongoDB document. You need to quote it in single or double quotes in Python in order to make it a string and use it in a PyMongo update expression.

Your second problem is, MongoDB's `update` command doesn't allow you set one field to the value of another, nor to rename a field. However, you can reshape all the documents in your collection using the `aggregate` command with a `$project` stage and store the results in a second collection using a `$out` stage.

Here's a complete example to play with:

```
db = MongoClient().test
collection = db.collection
collection.delete_many({})
collection.insert_one({
"valor" : {
    "AB" : {
        "X" : 0.0,
        "Y" : 142.6,
    },
    "FJ" : {
         "X" : 0.2,
         "Y" : 3.33}}})

collection.aggregate([{
    "$project": {
        "valor": {
            "AB": "$valor.AB",
            "FOJ": "$valor.FJ"
        }
    }
}, {
    "$out": "collection2"
}])
```

This is the dangerous part. First, check that "collection2" has all the documents you want, in the desired shape. Then:

```
collection.drop()
db.collection2.rename("collection")

import pprint
pprint.pprint(collection.find_one())
```